# How does a 64b Linux knows to manage a 32b application?

Tags: linux, 32bit-64bit

I understood that windows has a WOW64 subsystem for handling and running 32bit applications. And I am wondering what is in charge of the same procedures in linux and how to they operate.
(general O.S behavior and specific linux version wise, like centos6/7, debian, etc)

also, can you (and why) link between 64b library to a 32b one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just like windows has WOW64, most Linux distributions have `MultiArch` (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch) or equivalent, to provide 32 bit support in 64 bit systems

Comment: Thanks, I found the Debian explanations site more informative.